# Need SQL query to update the column using case when by joining two tables in Netezza Database

Tags: join, update, netezza

There are 2 tables : Sales & Transaction. I need to update the INDICATOR column of the Sales table using CASE WHEN by joining these two tables in Netezza database.

Using below query but not working.
Error - Update canceled: attempt to update a target row with values from multiple join rows

```
Update Sales s 
SET indicator = 
 CASE  
     WHEN  t.retail >= s.PRICe then 'Y'
     WHEN  t.retail <  s.PRICE then 'N'
     ELSE NULL END
FROM TRANSACTION t
     WHERE s.id = t.id and s.STORE_ID = t.store_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For some rows in the SALES table, you have multiple rows in the TRANSACTION table that match on the join condition.  So the system doesn't know which row from the TRANSACTION table it should use to extract the T.RETAIL value from.

This SQL should find you those "multiple rows".  To get your UPDATE query to work, you will need to decide how you want to limit the join so that just one row (from TRANSACTION) is returned per (id,store_id) pair.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    s.id,
    s.store_id
FROM
    sales s,
    transaction t
WHERE
    s.id = t.id
    AND s.store_id = t.store_id
GROUP BY
    2,
    3
HAVING
    cnt > 1
```